# unable to stop few lxc vms

Tags: lxc, lxd

im trying to stop few lxc vm but not working whereas other vms are able to.

```
admin1@oc-vm:~/my-stuff$ lxc ls
+-----------------+---------+------------------------+------+-----------------+-----------+
|      NAME       |  STATE  |          IPV4          | IPV6 |      TYPE       | SNAPSHOTS |
+-----------------+---------+------------------------+------+-----------------+-----------+
| infra-gitlab-01 | RUNNING | 10.118.89.234 (enp5s0) |      | VIRTUAL-MACHINE | 0         |
+-----------------+---------+------------------------+------+-----------------+-----------+
| infra-gitlab-02 | RUNNING | 10.118.89.125 (enp5s0) |      | VIRTUAL-MACHINE | 0         |
+-----------------+---------+------------------------+------+-----------------+-----------+
| infra-jfrog-01  | RUNNING | 10.118.89.148 (enp5s0) |      | VIRTUAL-MACHINE | 0         |
+-----------------+---------+------------------------+------+-----------------+-----------+
| infra-jfrog-02  | RUNNING | 10.118.89.10 (enp5s0)  |      | VIRTUAL-MACHINE | 0         |
+-----------------+---------+------------------------+------+-----------------+-----------+
| vm03            | STOPPED |                        |      | VIRTUAL-MACHINE | 0         |
+-----------------+---------+------------------------+------+-----------------+-----------+
admin1@oc-vm:~/my-stuff$
```

```
admin1@oc-vm:~/my-stuff$ lxc shell infra-gitlab-01 
root@infra-gitlab-01:~# reboot now

Session terminated, killing shell...
 ...killed.
admin1@oc-vm:~/my-stuff$ 
admin1@oc-vm:~/my-stuff$ 
admin1@oc-vm:~/my-stuff$ 
admin1@oc-vm:~/my-stuff$ 
admin1@oc-vm:~/my-stuff$ 
admin1@oc-vm:~/my-stuff$ 
admin1@oc-vm:~/my-stuff$ lxc ls
+-----------------+---------+------------------------+------+-----------------+-----------+
|      NAME       |  STATE  |          IPV4          | IPV6 |      TYPE       | SNAPSHOTS |
+-----------------+---------+------------------------+------+-----------------+-----------+
| infra-gitlab-01 | RUNNING | 10.118.89.234 (eth0)   |      | VIRTUAL-MACHINE | 0         |
+-----------------+---------+------------------------+------+-----------------+-----------+
| infra-gitlab-02 | RUNNING | 10.118.89.125 (enp5s0) |      | VIRTUAL-MACHINE | 0         |
+-----------------+---------+------------------------+------+-----------------+-----------+
| infra-jfrog-01  | RUNNING | 10.118.89.148 (enp5s0) |      | VIRTUAL-MACHINE | 0         |
+-----------------+---------+------------------------+------+-----------------+-----------+
admin1@oc-vm:~/my-stuff$ lxc  stop  infra-gitlab-01 
// prompt freezes
```

any suggestions/?